# How to store string tokens into array

Tags: java

I reference to some sample to extract each part of the user input successfully. However, it can only extract 1 times. There should be 2 loop for extracting multiple input and saving the tokens in array. I am stuck on the array, how could I do it?

> Question:
>
> Write a program that accepts string tokens in the format of token1:token2:token3:token4 , where : is used as delimiter to separate tokens. There should be two functions, ingest and appearance.
>
> - ingest takes a string, and stores it in the collection.
> - appearance takes a string as input . It returns a normalized value
>   between 0 to 1,  where the value represents the percentage of
>   appearances of stored tokens which have input as the prefix.
> - State the space and time complexity of your solution.

Expected Result:

```
ingest('McDonal:uk:employeeA')
ingest('McDonal:hk:employeeA')
ingest('McDonal:hk:employeeB')
ingest('McDonal:hk:employeeC')
ingest('fastfood')

appearance('McDonal')
# > 0.8
appearance('McDonal:hk')
# > 0.6
```

My Code:

```
 String input;
   
        
 // For user input
 Scanner sentense = new Scanner(System.in);
 input = sentense.nextLine();   
 String[] ingestWords = {};
       
             
 // Use ':' to seperate input
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ":");
 while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
   System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Comment: Try using `String.split()` to separate the tokens.

Comment: "stores it [a string] in a **collection**." As an _array_ is fixed length, use for instance a growing `ArrayList<String>`. A List is a Collection.

Comment: Regarding, _"... stores it in the collection."_, I imagine it's a generalization; an _array_ is technically a collection.  In other words they don't want you to use a _List_, which would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you address your problem in two steps.

First, the ingest part: you need to accept input words from the user and store each word in a `ArrayList<String>` instead of a fixed-size array, since you do not know in advance how many inputs you will get.

An example code could look like the following.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    List<String> ingestWords = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner sentence = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    while (sentence.hasNext()) {
        input = sentence.next();
            
        if (input.equals("exit")) { // To stop receiving input
            break;
        }
            
        ingestWords.add(input);         
    }
    sentence.close();
}
```

Second, the appearance part: given a string, you need to iterate over your list of words from the ingest part, and check which ones start with the given string.

For example, you can make a helper function like so.

```java
void hasPrefix(String word, String str) {
    return word.startsWith(str);
}
```

Applying this function to each word in `ingestWords` will give you the number of words that have `str` as a prefix. And you can figure out the percentage of appearance from it.